# Crop and resize image on clientside

Tags: image-processing, crop

Is it possible to work with client chosen images on client PC without uploading image to server.

If yes, what web programming language can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be done with `Flash`, `Silverlight` or a custom `Plugin/ActiveX` depending on the target browser.

Comment: So flash allows to edit image directly on user machine?
If it's true, then thanks a lot. I'll look into it. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use HTML5 Canvas, no need to use plugins or such.

Load the image, change the canvas size, and draw image. It's also possible to extract the result as a dataUrl.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        // draw cropped image
        var sourceX = 150;
        var sourceY = 0;
        var sourceWidth = 150;
        var sourceHeight = 150;
        var destWidth = sourceWidth;
        var destHeight = sourceHeight;
        var destX = canvas.width / 2 - destWidth / 2;
        var destY = canvas.height / 2 - destHeight / 2;

        context.drawImage(imageObj, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

All credit goes to:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done with javascript libraries like jQuery, MooTools, Prototype and script.aculo.us:

http://www.bitrepository.com/image-cropping-with-jquery-mootools-prototype-scriptaculous.html

Comment: As far as I know, while the cropping is arranged through a client side UI, the image has to be uploaded to the server first. The JS is just sending the coordinates to the server, and the server crops and scales. So, this doesn't fit the requirements of the question since the image must be uploaded first.

Comment: Actually, if you use HTML5 you can directly manipulate the raw pixel data in-the-browser.  See, for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Canvas/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

Comment: @Cole You can access local files using javascript.  For example: reading a file using HTML5, http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files , or running your javascript locally, like tiddlywiki does http://www.tiddlywiki.com/

Comment: Okay, it will be possible once all the browsers support Canvas and HTML5, but the projects on the page you linked to don't work in that way. . I've built an image upload system using imgAreaSelect. The actual scaling is taken care of on the server side, using gd/imagemagick. T

Comment: @Cole Just minor points, but it is possible in any browser that supports HTML5 canvas, which currently includes the latest versions of Firefox, Safari, and Chrome.  Also, it is still possible to manipulate the image data if you load the page from a local computer, though not true crop/resize.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a image cropper by javascript, take a look at: https://github.com/supnate/icropper . It provides the user interface for cropping but not real cropping the image.